# How to calculate average dollars sold per hour?

Tags: excel, average

I have a spreadsheet that has in and out times per transaction and how many dollars each transaction was.

I am trying to have the spreadsheet update with another column that will tell me

1. How many transactions I have per hour, (i.e between 7AM & 7:59 AM, between 8AM & 8:59AM, etc...
2. How many dollars are spent per hour.

[image]

I have tried average if, and all kinds of other functions. But I cannot get the time frame to read properly in the formulas.

Comment: In any of the rows in the example, you do not cross the top of the hour. How will a transaction that starts at 8:50 and ends at 9:05 be considered: in the 8:00-8:49, or 9:00-9:59? What if the transaction is from 8:50 through 10:05? Do you have transactions that start and do not end?

Comment: Tip: https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: As long as all transactions are counted in the same hour (eg `Time In`), you can simply use `AVERAGEIFS`.

Comment: It would be considered in the 8'oclock hour. There are no transactions that do not end, unless of course someone miskeyed something.

Comment: The issue I am having, is I cannot get my formula to read the times, it is something I am not keying correctly I am sure. averageifs(a:a, >="7:00 AM, <= "7:59 AM", e:e"???

Comment: "many transactions I have per hour" <-- u r referring to time In.. or time Out?

Comment: Time in would be when the transaction would count